# Clickable Google Sheets in Webpage

Tags: jquery, google-sheets, embed

I need help with a project someone wants me to do for them.

He has a Google Sheet that has notes taken on it (so when you click the cell it pops up with more information about that cell) that he wants on a webpage.

What can I do to have these pop-ups in the web page? If I can't use the embedded Google Sheets can I use jQuery to code something that works the same?

I just don't know what it would be called in HTML/jQuery, I've tried googling and nobody has reinvented their notes procedure as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in a published google sheets document, notes cannot be displayed. However, I do have a solution, albeit a crude one:

```
<iframe src="shareablelink" style="position:relative; top:-100px;”></iframe>
```

Here I am placing the shareable link in an iframe, and moving it up so that only the data is displayed. The only edit that is required is to change the shareable link's permissions to view only. Normally I do not condone this messy and uncouth code, but this is the only workaround I was able to create that is viable.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Ah I understand! That's actually really cool I didn't know you could do that

Thank you!